# searching huge text file

Tags: java, text, lucene

I have a text file consisting of ~40 million of lines in the form of a key/value, I want to retrieve the values given the key within seconds (2-3) max, I don't have enough memory to store all of them in JVM memory as a hashmap, can I use system storage + some indexing to achieve that ? 
i've been reading about lucene, but not sure if it's what am looking for.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search a "text string" in the key or in the value you could use [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/). **Lucene** is a full-featured text search engine library but **you can use it also simply for search the exact match** of the **key** value. I use Lucene with more than 60 millions of documents and I have **less than 1 second** for every search.

Otherwise if you want **only** a **key**/**value** store you can use a NOSql Key/Value database like [Redis](https://redis.io/), but I haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think Hadoop it's a better tool for this task: just split the original file between the slaves. The map function is performing a search on each part of the original file, and the reduce is the combination of all findings. If the keys are unique, only one slave will provide the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Lucene is for free text search. The quickest solution if you don't have to use the text file would be to use a database. 40 million records is a lot, but even so finding a single record using a unique index (on the key) should be much faster than 2-3 seconds. You can use an embedded database like HSQLDB, just make sure that you configure it to use disk storage!

If you need to keep the text file, create a TreeMap from key to offset into the file if you can afford to store that in memory. Sounds messy though.